# Access Denied error jQuery .load

Tags: jquery

I have a page that loads a div from another page on successful submission of a form. It works in all browsers except IE 7 and 8 where I get the following error:

Here is the error code: Error: Access Denied

my code:

```
$("#formTwo").validate({
        groups: { asset: "trade_futures trade_fx trade_equities" },
        errorElement: "em",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.parent("li"));
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#processing").show();
            var dataString = $(form).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: $(form).attr('method'),
                    url: form.action,
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data, status) {
                         $("#currentUser, #newUser, #submitContain, #processing").hide();
                         $("#contain").load('download-download #req');
                    },
                    error: function (data, status) {
                        $("#newUser, #submitContain").hide();
                        $("#contain").html("error");
                    }
                });
            return false;
           },
       //rest of rules and messages
```

I have seen a lot of discussion about this but none of the solutions seem to work. I have tried loading from google cdn, microsoft cdn, jquery cdn and from a local copy of jquery-1.4.2.js but nothing works!

Is there an alternate way you use to load a div from another page on success?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design can you share some markup, it must trying to append an element where it should not supposed to be, e.g append an li to a div and ie really does not like this, other browsers are more forgiving (wrongly?)

Comment: @redsquare - its a long page, here's the link http://tiny.cc/asuss basically when you submit either form on the page, it should remove both forms and insert the table. Works in all other browsers.

Comment: Does "download-download" page load if you just type its address into your browser?

Comment: @sje397 yes http://www.kinetick.com/V3/download-download.php

Comment: @redsquare line 79 <div class="rColpurchase" id="req">

Comment: :) ok another one....I cant see an id of contain!

Comment: on the page http://www.kinetick.com/V3/download-trading-software.php aprx line 79 <div class="rColpurchase" id="contain">

Comment: I swear the find in Chrome is bust.>! sorry

Comment: I was correct originally - your trying to post to a different domain "http://www.ninjatrader-support2.com/sugar/Nt6.5Lead.php"

Comment: @redsquare, my apologies, I thought you meant the content I was trying to load was cross domain. So that applies to scripts as well?

Comment: @Dirty - you can load scripts (by injecting a `<script>` tag) across domains.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design updated my answer, it is not the remote script, you are calling .load on a remote domain

Comment: @redsquare - I was under the impression the cross domain policy only dealt with content being loaded from across domains, I see the error of my misguided thinking. I fixed the script location, it works. Thanks for being patient and helping me learn.

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design - anytime, good luck with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form action you are using to get the url for the ajax method (.load) is that of another domain namely "http://www.ninjatrader-support2.com/sugar/Nt6.5Lead.php.

You cannot do ajax calls cross domain. You are following foul of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

The simplest way to see is open the IE debugging tool and select the script tag and press start debugging. Fill in the form fields and click download, the debugging tool will kick in and show you the following

[image]

Notice the url in the watch window on the right.

Comment: @Matt Ball not all browsers stop you from doing it, however it will not work in ie - http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/ ....!

Comment: @redsquare @Matt Ball, i wish I was doing it cross domain, id use cURL and be done with it. This is loading from a page on the same url, i apologize for not being clear

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design, no worries.

Comment: @redsquare - any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @Dirty Bird Design does it submit the form?